# getting an onClick event to select and show the select change on an html select form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Goal:** Using an `onClick` event to run a function.  The function is designed to change the value and display the selected value in a `<select>` element in the HTML form.  I realize that `.val` only applies the value. 

It actually is changing the select text to empty.

I've tried using `.attr` and applying a selected attribute but that isn't appearing to work either.

**`onClick`, I want the value to change to the color, and also the color to display in the select box.  If the select box dropdown is triggered, I still want the other color options to be able to be chosen as well.**

Any way to do this?

```
<script>
function changeColor(color) {
  $(".select-color").val("'" + color + "'");
}
</script>
```

SELECT BOX

```
<select class="select-color"><option value="">SELECT A COLOR</option><option value="BLACK">BLACK</option><option value="RED">RED</option></select>
```

LINK

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="changeColor('RED')">CHANGE TO RED</a>
```

Comment: NOTE: I am not trying to change BACKGROUND COLOR...I am trying to change the text in the select to the color RED.  Red is an option.  I want it to appear as though the user has dropped down the select and selected RED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the body of `changeColor` to this :

```
$(".select-color").val(color);
```

You don't want or need those additional quotes you were including around the value.

Comment: The quotes around were messing it up.  That solved the problem.  I thought I had already tried that but apparently not

Answer (score 0):

Let say we want to change back-color to red, so we need to use css method to change color. Please find working example below:

```js
function changeColor(color) {
  $(".select-color").val(color);
  $(".select-color").css("background-color", color);

}
```

```html
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select class="select-color">
  <option value="">SELECT A COLOR</option>
  <option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
  <option value="RED">RED</option>
</select>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="changeColor('RED')">CHANGE TO RED</a>
```

Comment: NOTE: I am not trying to change BACKGROUND COLOR...I am trying to change the text in the select to the color RED. Red is an option. I want it to appear as though the user has dropped down the select and selected RED

Comment: fixed as per Robin's answer.  My quotes were messing it up

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function changeColor(color) {
  console.log(color);
  $(".select-color option[value=" + color + "]").prop('selected',true);
  
  ;
  
 
  
  
}
</script>
SELECT BOX

<select class="select-color">
<option value="">SELECT A COLOR</option>
<option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
<option value="RED">RED</option>
</select>
LINK

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="changeColor('RED')">CHANGE TO RED</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to change the value of select dropdown and body background color.

function changeColor(color) {
            $(".select-color").val(color);


    }